# EDITED - How to import CSS from 3th party lib - REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, pack

I get stuck while I tried to importing CSS from a 3th party lib. Some libs requires in addition to npm install LIB , import the css.

After install lib I import the css inside my component like this

```
import Cards from 'react-credit-cards'    
import 'react-credit-cards/lib/styles.scss'
```

Then use the component

```
<Cards
  number='XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX'
  name='CARD HOLDER NAME'
  expiry='MONTH/YEAR'
  cvc='CVV/CVC'/>
```

Running by the first time, I get errors (Module not found) in import line.

Then I change the webpack to load this files on node-modules, like this:

```
{
        test: /.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1'),
        include: [
    >>>      /node_modules/, <<<
          /flexboxgrid/
        ]
      },
...
}
```

Now, It don’t pop errors, but when I run the code, the CSS is not loaded. I also tried to get the css copy and paste add in my global css file, but still won’t work.

Finally, my question =D . To load 3th party lib CSS , I need to setup something more on webpack.config?

**EDIT**.

After changing my webpack file, the CSS is now loading. But, - look at this image below - the CSS when pass thought the webpack generate some HASH to identify the classes.
The card component is still with the original names, and the CSS generated is with this hash.

CARD COMPONENT

[image: rcss]

CSS OF react-credit-cards

[image]

Here is the loaders part of my `webpack.config.json`

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

const PATHS = {
  app: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  build: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
  assets: path.join(__dirname, 'assets')
}

const common = {
  entry: [
    PATHS.app
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: PATHS.app,
        loaders: ['babel']
      },
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1'),
        include: /flexboxgrid/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1!sass?sourceMap'),
        exclude: /flexboxgrid/
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i,
        loader: 'url?name=/imgs/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules')
    ],
    packageMains: ['browser', 'web', 'browserify', 'main', 'style']
  }
}
...
```

Comment: Just an observation.. the file you are trying to load has .scss extension.

Comment: Did you import the component too? like `import Cards from 'react-credit-cards';`

Comment: Hi Lucas Costa. Yes, I also import the Cards.

Comment: Hi Pedro Gabriel Lima, yes, this snippets includes only the css, I'll edit to include the scss loader too.

Comment: @ViniciusPaldês Hi, Vinicius! Very strange that your css classes get mangled like this - looks like some hashes. Could it be some minification/uglyfication? Are you sure, the config you provided is complete? Could you try my config instead?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're trying to load SCSS file, not a CSS file.

Corresponding part of your `webpack.config.js` can look like this:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // to load from your src folder  
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules') // to load from node_modules
]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css') // extract css and sass files into server.css bundle
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.(s?css|sass)$/, // css, scss and sass will be passed to sass-loader, then css-loader and then to ExtractTextPlugin and css will be extracted to app.css
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader', // if can't extract css, inline it into JS bundle
          use: [
            { loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true} },
            { loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true} }
          ]
        })
      },
```

This configuration is for Webpack2, I assume the differences with Webpack3 are minimal.

Comment: Hi Boris, thanks for your answer. I added this line in Path to join node_modules. But I got a new problem. I'll edit the post so you can see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import scss and not css.
You will need a sass loader.

Do,

`npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev`

Then,

Add the following loader to your webpack config.

`{
test: /\.scss$/,
include: paths.appSrc,
loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
}`

Comment: Hi Priyesh , Thanks for your answer. I got this scss loader too. I edit my post for you guys can see the whole webpack config file.